# Insert Csv file values into table apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to insert bulk values into the table through an excel.csv file.

I have created a file browser item on the page, now in the process have to write insert code for this to insert the excel values into the table.

the following table I have created: NON_DYNAMIC_USER_GROUPS 
                           columns: ID,NAME,GROUP,GROUP_TYPE.

Need to create insert process code for this.

Comment: Don't use the Salesforce `apex` tags for `oracle-apex` questions.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the Excel2Collection plugin for converting any form of Excel document into rows in an Oracle table.
http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/process-type-plugin/excel2collections_271.html

PL/SQL already written, and formulated into an APEX plugin, making it easy to use.

It is possible to uncompress the code and convert it to using your own table, instead of apex_collections, which are limited to 50 columns/fields.